# How to read the value and output the value in C++

Tags: c++, oop, get, set

first of all am very new to C++. I am having some problem with my code. The program should able to get/read the value user entered and output it back. I tried get/set C++ methods, but am having some problem with getting and outputting the value in my main. The following is my code,

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class Store {
    public:
        //get and Set Price
        void setPrice(int x){
            price = x;
        }
        int getPrice(){
            return price;
        }

        //Get and set % Marked Up
        void setPercentageMarkedUp(int y){
            markedUpPrice = y;
        }
        int getPercentageMarkedUp(){
            return markedUpPrice;
        }

        //Get and set percentage Sales tax
        void setPercentageSalesTax(int y){
            percSalesTax = y;
        }
        int getPercentageSalesTax(){
            return percSalesTax;
        }

    private:
        int price;
        int markedUpPrice;
        int percSalesTax;
    };

    int main(){
        int price;
        Store obj;
        cout << "enter the Original Price of the item: "<<endl;
        obj.getPrice();
        cout<<"the value is:"<<price<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

As am very new to both C++ and StackOverflow, please dont downgrade me for asking this simple question. I know its very basic. Will definitely appreciate those who helps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't tag C++ questions as C.

Comment: You never assign `price` in your `main()`, you probably want `price = obj.getPrice();`.

Comment: I tried `int main(){
    Store obj;
    price = obj.getPrice();
    cout << "enter price" << price << endl;
    cin >>price;`
But it returned me an error called `use of undeclared identifier 'price' `error

Comment: @Blacky It should be `int  price = obj.getPrice();`. Please read a book about the basics before coming to ask here. We require a minimum of knowledge, and Stack Overflow certainly isn't the right place to get it.

Comment: Yeah, I have done like that. But it returns value `0`

Comment: @Blacky Sure, you never called `obj.setPrice()` before.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ: Can you please show me how to do that? Have tried a lot, not enough time to go through the books now. Thats why..

Comment: You should ask whoever gave you this assignment to help you understand it.

Comment: Mr.Jonathan how can I ask it to a book?

Comment: @Blacky Read the section before the exercise again.

Comment: Did that navta. Is it the right way to use getter and setter here? why not cout and cin methods?

Comment: @Blacky _"why not cout and cin methods?"_ Because that would make the `Store` class less flexible to reuse it in a different context.

Comment: The part *"the value user entered"* looks like it should involve `cin >> originalPrice`. And then perhaps a call to `setPrice` to set the price in the store.

Comment: Please don't use hollow phrases like *"having some problem"*. Nobody has any clue what that means. By the way, your tone is inappropriate. Before you talk about others helping you, how about asking yourself if this question helps Stackoverflow?

Comment: ^^ OK, then, why should SO contributors help you?

Comment: Thanks to only navta. Rest of them are like showing off like they are pros in programming

Comment: I get so frutrated because, I've said in the beginning that i am new to programming and stackoverrflow. the first "fantastic/"clever" " guy rated me down in the beginning, which made me can't ask a question anymore. I have already requested dont grade me down. But that "Einsteen" graded me down

Comment: @juanchopanza. Thanks a loooot buddy

Comment: You got rated down because your question was inherently poor.  Try calling your garage and telling them only 'my car will not work right' - they will just put the phone down because you are a timewaster.  You tried the same attitude with us: 'I am having some problem'.  It did not work well, and so you decided it's eveyone else's fault but your own, slagging off the skilled and experienced developers who contribute to SO.   Tough - we're wise to you, mate - another deadbeat timewaster.

Comment: 'us' who are you?? :D

Answer (score 0):

Just need to update the main as follows

```
int main(){
    Store obj;
    int n_price;
    cout << " Enter Original Price: " << endl;
    cin >> n_price;
    obj.setPrice(n_price);
    cout << "Original Price: " << n_price<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks everyone. :)